# Excel Formula Help (Subtract 1 from values in column until 0 then move on to next value)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with a formula that will just subtract 1 from the first cell until it hits 0 and then subtract 1 from the next cell until it hits 0 and so on and so forth. That way I don't have to worry about the values continually changing. I am new to the site so sorry if my previous explanation was not clear enough. I basically just need a formula that will subtract 1 from a cell in a column until 0 and then move to next cell. I have attached pics also.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you want to have initiate the subtraction. It sounds like you want some event to occur to drain the first cell and then the next one and then the next, but the end result is zero for all of them. I doubt you want a formula that just shows zero. There must be some "unit of activity" that causes column B to decrement. Are we counting something? In your comment to cybernetic nomad you mention columns I and J. Are these on the same sheet with Column A (i.e., Line Assignment)? How are they used? What are the conditions upon which a subtraction should occur?

Comment: Hi. I'm new and was trying to simplify things in my post but it seems is confusing. I need to assign people to lines based on needs. I have a list of lines that need staffing. ex: Line 1:8, Line 2:5, etc. Originally i wanted a formula to get the first > 0 value and assign to that line. So in this case the badge would be scanned to line 1 until it hit 0 and then assigned to line 2. The formula works until my first line is filled because then my first >0 value is line 2 so it changes all the previous values to line 2. So I'm looking to just subtract 1 from the list until 0 then move to nxt line.

Comment: "I have tried using the max function" <--- how does the function look like.. would you mind sharing the sceenshot of you expected outcome? I'll help to clarify the question.

Comment: I tried referencing this https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/632034-subtract-amount-cell-until-reaches-0-then-move-subtract-next-amount.html but could not figure out how to tailor it to my need of just subtracting 1 until cell is emptied and then moving to the next cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want the negatives to show use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2-1<0,"",A2-1),"")
```

And drag across as many cells as required

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. I have tried using a formula that will return the highest non zero value [INDEX('Line Assignment'!$J$4:$J$20,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('Line Assignment'!$I$4:$I$20>0,),0))] but the issue I have with this formula is that it continually changes every time i hit enter. So I was looking instead of using the above formula to get the first non zero value instead just subtract 1 from a cell until it hits 0 and then move to the next cell in the column. I'm not sure it is clear when just explaining so I tried to provide the example in my post.

Comment: At this point it is becoming less and less clear what it is you are trying to achieve. I suggest you take five and think about how to clearly and concisely explain it. Showing mock data and expected result.

Comment: I'd provided 3 pictures previously. And I don't know how to explain it more clearly. I needed a formula that would pull the first non zero value in a column. Which I had but the formula wouldn't stick because the reference changes every time the first non 0 value changes. It's similar to if i wanted to use the formula now() to record time records but you have to use it in a specific way so that the recorded time sticks and doesn't just keep changing to the current time. But I figured it out. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your responses. I figured it out in two different ways. The first way is by using a macro to deduct from the first non 0 cell in the column and then move to the next. The next way was to use a circular reference to get my value to stick. Similar to the way you have to use the NOW() function with a circular reference to get the recorded time to stick and not always change to whatever the current time is.